# Homework problem: Seeking clarification on conceptual populations.

Tags: statistics

I'm starting my first probability & statistics course today and I'm seeking clarification for the solution to a homework problem. I will quote the problem below:

**Textbook Question:**
"Many universities and colleges have instituted supplemental instruction (SI) programs, in which a student facilitator meets regularly with a small group of students enrolled in the course to promote discussion of course material and enhance subject mastery. Suppose that students in a large statistics course are randomly divided into a control group that will not participate in SI and a treatment group that will participate. At the end of the term, each student’s total score in the course is determined.

**a)** Are the scores from the SI group a sample from an existing population? If so, what is it? If not, what is the relevant conceptual population?"

**Textbook's Answer:** "No, the relevant conceptual population is all scores of all students who participate in the SI in conjunction with this particular statistics course."

I don't understand this because I thought the answer would have been that the scores from the SI group were a sample from the scores of the entire class, i.e. those in the control group AND the treatment group (the existing population).

Can someone please help me understand how they got to their answer? I appreciate any help you can provide.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks everyone for your useful insight, it really helped :D